Formulas for type I, II, and III SS in R's car::Anova()
In the Anova() function of the car package one can specify whether the ANOVA should use type I, II, or III sum of squares to obtain F values. I tried to figure out which formulas this function uses to calculate these sums of squares. Unfortunately I failed. Thus, I'd be very happy of one could help me figuring this out ... Thanks a lot in advance!
Here is an example for 3 different models using type I, II and III SS calculations using R:
library(car)
data <- mtcars
data$am <- as.factor(am)
data$gear <- as.factor(gear)

mod1 <- summary(aov(lm(mtcars$mpg ~ am * gear, data = data)))
mod2 <- Anova(lm(mtcars$mpg ~ am * gear, data = data), type = "II")
mod3 <- Anova(lm(mtcars$mpg ~ am * gear, data = data), type = "III")

mod1
mod2
mod3

You can easily see that the F values are all different, depending on which kind of SS type is used.

This is a complex subject!  I suspect your question will probably be closed as off-topic for SO, but the information you need can be found here. The document is written in the context of SAS rather than R, but the concepts are transferrable.  Good luck!

The method it uses depends on the type of model you give it.  You need to give example code if you need help finding the source.

@Limey Thanks a lot. Will have a luck. So far I found in no book and only a handful of papers a somewhat proper explanation of the differences, which still left me with open questions. Let's see whether this SAS book can fill my gaps ;)

I just noticed the errors in my answer (which copied your code).  You should change the  as.factor() lines to get the source from the dataframe, e.g. data$am <- as.factor(data$am).

In a comment, @Limey gave a link to a paper about the theory of these calculations.  In summary, type I sums of squares are sequential ones.  You are testing whether each term adds significantly to the model given that only previous terms have been included.  The other types test whether each term adds to the model, given that a different collection of other variables is included:

Type II:  All terms are included except ones containing the given term.  In your example, that would be am given gear, gear given am, and am*gear given both am and gear.

Type III and IV are similar to Type II, but they adjust for unbalanced designs (i.e. ones where levels of factors or interactions of factors don't all have the same counts).  The details of the adjustment are in @Limey's reference.  Do note that Anova() is documented to be different from SAS for Type III tests; I think you'll need to check one of the references for the details.
I'd start with


Fox, J. and Weisberg, S. (2019) An R Companion to Applied Regression, Third Edition, Sage.
On the other hand, aov() does none of those types.  It is designed for balanced designs, and won't give useful results for your unbalanced example.
If you want to see how the calculations are implemented in the car package, you need go through the following steps:

Find the class of the object you are passing to Anova():

library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData
data <- mtcars
data$am <- as.factor(data$am)
data$gear <- as.factor(data$gear)

fit <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~ am * gear, data = data)
class(fit)
#> [1] "lm"

Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.1.0
So you are working with an object of class "lm", and Anova(fit) will call car:::Anova.lm.

You can print that function.  It's fairly long because of a lot of checking of inputs, but near the end you can see that it will call car:::Anova.II.lm or car:::Anova.III.lm, depending on the test type that you have chosen.

You can print each of those functions to see the
details of the calculations.


